# MySQL - database design - how to create foreign key to multiple level parent tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

this is the first time i have created a database with multiple levels (question sub sections) and i am unsure of how to create the foreign keys in the answer table

(note, my question table structure may not be ideal)

currently i have a 3 tier question system:
1.1.1, 1.1.2...
with one table per level

at the end i have an answer table where i am trying to create a foreign key to the above structure.
is the correct way 3 separate foreign keys?, one to each table? - which i have done below.
However i feel this may well not be right. I may just be over complicating things too.

code is below, hopefully it is clear

```
create table if not exists company(
id_comp int not null,
company_name varchar(255),
country varchar(128),,

primary key (id_comp)
);



create table if not exists ques_l1(
id_ques_l1 int not null auto_increment,
desc_ques_l1 varchar(128),

primary key (id_ques_l1)
);

create table if not exists ques_l2(
id_ques_l2 int not null auto_increment,
id_ques_l1 int,
desc_ques_l2 varchar(128),

primary key (id_ques_l2),
foreign key (id_ques_l1) references ques_l1(id_ques_l1)

);

create table if not exists ques_l3(
id_ques_l3 int not null auto_increment,
id_ques_l1 int,
id_ques_l2 int,
desc_ques_l3 varchar(128),

primary key (id_ques_l3),
foreign key (id_ques_l2) references ques_l2(id_ques_l2)
);



create table if not exists answers(
id_answer int auto_increment not null,
id_comp int,
year int(4),
id_ques_l1 int,
id_ques_l2 int,
id_ques_l3 int,
score int,

primary key (id_answer),
foreign key (id_comp) references company(id_comp),
foreign key (id_ques_l1) references ques_l1(id_ques_l1),
foreign key (id_ques_l2) references ques_l2(id_ques_l2),
foreign key (id_ques_l3) references ques_l3(id_ques_l3)
);
```

Comment: is it possible i only need one foreign key linked to ques_l3 table - foreignkey(id_ques_l1, id_ques_l2, id_ques_l3) references ques_l3(id_ques_l1, id_ques_l2, id_ques_l3)?

Comment: `FOREIGN KEYs` do not solve all problems.  Some integrity checks need to be done in the app code.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have the questions split across three tables? Why not have them all in one table?

Comment: im not really sure when to use FKs, i have decided to abandon the 3 table system and go for one table (Tommcatt). My idea (probably wrong) was to have a key then of the form (ques_l1, ques_l2, Ques_l3) - this is also probably not right and doesnt seem to work anyway